# Playframework 2.6 [Scala]: How to compile *.jsx files into *.js files

Tags: reactjs, playframework

I could include React into my application, using the following library dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.6.3"
libraryDependencies += "org.webjars.bower" % "react" % "16.1.0"
```

However, I'm looking for a solution to compile the `*.jsx` files into `*.js` files. The solutions regarding this topic, mostly point to the following step:

1. Add a sbt plugin `project/plugins.sbt`:

   addSbtPlugin("com.github.ddispaltro" % "sbt-reactjs" % "0.6.8")
2. Enable `SbtWeb` plugin, in `build.sbt`.

However I cannot compile my project:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.github.ddispaltro#sbt-reactjs;0.6.8: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.github.ddispaltro:sbt-reactjs:0.6.8 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.github.ddispaltro:sbt-reactjs:0.6.8 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (/Users/daverose/playProject/app/project/plugins.sbt#L3-4)
[warn]        +- default:play-app-build:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.ddispaltro#sbt-reactjs;0.6.8: not found
```

Is there any other way to deal with this? Because I don't want to revert my Scala or Sbt version.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that SBT can't resolve (download) the `sbt-reactjs` jar. This artifact doesn't seem to be hosted on Maven Central where SBT looks for artifacts by default. The Readme on their [github page](https://github.com/dispalt/sbt-reactjs) says

> The artifact is hosted as part of the [community plugins](https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Community/Bintray-For-Plugins.html) via bintray service.

so you're gonna have to add Bintray to your list of resolvers to fetch `sbt-reactjs` from there:

```
resolvers += Resolver.url(
  "bintray-sbt-plugin-releases",
   url("http://dl.bintray.com/content/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer; however this would not solve the problem. Have you used it with play 2.6?If so how your build.sbt looks like in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the SBT version to 1.3.0 makes the problem more clear.

sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.github.ddispaltro:sbt-reactjs;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:0.6.8

not found: http://dl.bintray.com/content/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.github.ddispaltro/sbt-reactjs/**scala_2.12/sbt_1.0**/0.6.8/ivys/ivy.xml

This is the only version available -> https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.github.ddispaltro/sbt-reactjs/**scala_2.10/sbt_0.13**/0.6.8/

There are no modern versions of sbt-reactjs published.

Comment: P.S.  Thanks for the resolver above.  That pointed me in the right direction.